When describing a person's traits, how should I use the present tense of the verb "to be"?
Specifically, which form is correct in this sentence?

Her enthusiasm and empathy is invaluable.

or

Her enthusiasm and empathy are invaluable.

While "is" sounds more natural, I know the two traits are plural. Could you clarify the correct usage and explain the relevant grammar rules?

It's two things so it's plural (if it was two things that form a unit, like mortar and pestle or pride and joy, it might be different, but this is just two entirely separate qualities). Why do you think "is" sounds more natural - would you prefer "Her cat and dog is cute"?

@StuartF Coordinations of abstract nouns often get treated as singular.

@alphabet As established phrases, sure ("rest and relaxation," "research and development"), but otherwise? and to silli, seconding Stuart's suggestion: if "I know it should be X, but feel like it should be Y," it helps if you can explain anything about why you feel like it should be Y.

In trying to determine verb agreement, think of it this way:
"Her skill is invaluable."
"Her skills are invaluable."
A singular noun, "skill," goes with "is". A plural noun and multiple nouns go with "are". (Also notice, a "noun goes" and "nouns go")
"Enthusiasm and empathy" are two characteristics. If it feels like that phrase should take the singular verb form, it might be because you are thinking of the sentence as saying "her character is invaluable" and not as what it says -- "her two characteristics are invaluable."
